# TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'model' (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a data migration for the purpose of instantiating several Mineral objects for the database. Upon running `python manage.py migrate` in the console I get the error: `TypeError: Mineral() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model'`.

I can't find anything resembling this keyword that Django is raising. What is causing this error which is preventing model instances from being created?

```
#models.py

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Mineral(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=60, null="")
    image_filename = models.CharField(max_length=65, null="")
    image_caption = models.CharField(max_length=410, null="")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, null="")
    formula = models.CharField(max_length=280, null="")
    strunz_classification = models.CharField(max_length=110, null="")
    color = models.CharField(max_length=195, null="")
    crystal_system = models.CharField(max_length=130, null="")
    unit_cell = models.CharField(max_length=140, null="")
    crystal_symmetry = models.CharField(max_length=130, null="")
    cleavage = models.CharField(max_length=170, null="")
    mohs_scale_hardness = models.CharField(max_length=70, null="")
    luster = models.CharField(max_length=75, null="")
    streak = models.CharField(max_length=60, null="")
    diaphaneity = models.CharField(max_length=80, null="")
    optical_properties = models.CharField(max_length=85, null="")
    refractive_index = models.CharField(max_length=125, null="")
    crystal_habit = models.CharField(max_length=240, null="")
    specific_gravity = models.CharField(max_length=70, null="") 
    group = models.CharField(max_length=20, null="")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

```
# retrieve_json.py

import json

def pull_json(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    return data
```

```
from django.db import migrations
import os.path

from ..data.retrieve_json import pull_json

def load_mineral_data(apps, schema_editor):

    Mineral = apps.get_model('minerals', 'Mineral')

    mineral_data = pull_json(os.path.abspath('minerals/data/minerals.json'))

    for m in mineral_data:
        Mineral.objects.create(**m)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('minerals', '0001_define_mineral'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_mineral_data, migrations.RunPython.noop)
    ]
```

Comment: I cant help but I can say that the full stack  trace would help others to help you :)

Comment: My guess is that is here Mineral.objects.create(**m)

Comment: issue might be in ***`Mineral.objects.create(**m)`***

Comment: Consider of posting fulls stack trace.

Comment: I scanned the JSON data and found there was an unnecessary extra key. That appeared to be the problem.